# Logging out to a specific view in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, stack-navigator

I'm a beginner to react native development. At the moment I'm trying to set my navigation for the login logout process. This is my app flow right now `Home -> SignIn -> Dashboard`. Now when the user clicks the logout button in the dashboard it should go back to Home screen. This works well for the first time, but the problem is, if a user is already logged in, it skips the `Home` and `SignIn` and goes straight to `Dashboard` and if I try to log out from there it actually pushes to new `Home` view while keeping `Dashboard` in the stack and when I `SignIn` it does a pop transition to `Dashboard` showing the old state data. I did some digging and its said that react doesn't have provision to pop up out to specific view and we may have to use a hack to replace the screen but I'm not sure how to proceed on that. Below is my current code for the stack navigator and logout process.

```
const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: {
    screen: SplashScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null
    })
  },
SignIn: {
    screen: SignIn,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
Dashboard: {
    screen: Dashboard,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
});

const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  { Navigator: { screen: Navigator } },
  { contentComponent: NavigationDrawer }
);

//In Dashboard
logoutUser = () => {
//Perform API call to logout user
this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");

}
```

Comment: Why don't you try something like that https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html#docsNav? You can also use this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen Name') and clean the navigation history afterwards

Comment: you may want to use [switchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html) for this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SwitchNavigator,

```html
const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator({
  //Drawer Optons and indexing
  Screen1: {
    //Title
    screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 1',
      drawerIcon: <Image
      source={require('../assets/drawer.png')}
      style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
    />
    },
  },
  Screen2: {
    //Title
    screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 2',
      drawerIcon: <Image
      source={require('../assets/drawer.png')}
      style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
    />
    },
  },
},
{
  contentComponent: DrawerContent
});

const onboardingStackNavigator = createStackNavigator( {
  Home: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: "Login",
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerBackTitle: 'Back',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: headerBackgroundColor,

      },
      headerTintColor: headerTintColor,
    })
  },
  Signup: {
    screen: Signup,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: "SignUp",
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerBackTitle: 'Back',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: headerBackgroundColor,
      },
    })
  },},
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
)

const AppNavigator = createAnimatedSwitchNavigator(
    {   
      onboarding:onboardingStackNavigator,
      Drawer: {
        screen: DrawerNavigatorExample
      }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'onboarding',
        transition: (
          <Transition.In type='fade'></Transition.In>
        )  
    },

   );

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default AppContainer;
```